# Mock parent class __init__ method

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to write some unittests on a class which is derived from another, but I have some difficulties to mock the parent class **init** method, which afaik you cannot, so I am looking for suggestion.

Here an example of how are my classes

Imported.py

```
class Imported():
    def __init__(self, a="I am Imported"):
        print("a:{}".format(a))
```

Parent.py

```
from Imported import Imported

class Parent(object):

    parent_list = ["PARENT"]

    def __init__(self, a="I am Parent"):
        imported = Imported(a)
```

Derived.py

```
from Parent import Parent

class Derived(Parent):

    Parent.parent_list.append("DERIVED")
```

In my unittests I want to verify that Parent.parent_list == ["PARENT", "DERIVED"] when I instantiate an object from the Derived class, Derived().

Both of this solution doesn't work

test_Derived.py

```
import unittest
from mock import patch

from Derived import Derived


class test_Derived(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("Derived.Parent.__init__")
    def test_init_001(self, mock_parent_init):
        a = Derived("I am Derived")
        mock_parent_init.assert_called_with("I am Derived")
        self.assertEquals(a.parent_list, ["PARENT", "DERIVED"])

    @patch("Derived.Imported.Imported")
    def test_init_002(self, mock_parent_init):
        a = Derived("I am Derived")
        mock_parent_init.assert_called_with("I am Derived")
        self.assertEquals(a.parent_list, ["PARENT", "DERIVED"])
```

test_init_001 fails with

```
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'MagicMock'
```

test_init_002 fails with

```
ImportError: No module named Parent.Imported
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why exactly does `Parent.__init__` need to be mocked? Why not just mock `Imported`?

Comment: Your second test needs to mock `Parent.Imported`.

Comment: Last but not least, you modified `Parent.parent_list` *in place*, so both `Parent.parent_list` and `Derived.parent_list` refer to the same object. So `Parent.parent_list` now contains `"DERIVED"`. You probably want to create a copy for `Derived` instead: `parent_list = Parent.parent_list + ["DERIVED"]`. Your tests may want to check for this.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For the first solution, change the return value of the `__init__` method to `None`.

```
@patch("Derived.Parent.__init__")
def test_init_001(self, mock_parent_init):
    mock_parent_init.return_value = None  # <---
    a = Derived("I am Derived")
    mock_parent_init.assert_called_with("I am Derived")
    self.assertEquals(a.parent_list, ["PARENT", "DERIVED"])
```

For the second solution, patch `Parent.Imported`:

```
@patch("Parent.Imported")  # <---
def test_init_002(self, mock_parent_init):
    a = Derived("I am Derived")
    mock_parent_init.assert_called_with("I am Derived")
    self.assertEquals(a.parent_list, ["PARENT", "DERIVED"])
```

Comment: I was trying to test that a class was initialized with the right parameters, then a method called on that instance correctly, by mocking `__init__` and the method (let's call it `foo()`). The mocked `foo` method registered no calls until I set the return value of `__init__` to None. (I assume this is because the initialization in the code was broken by the mock of `__init__`, although setting `side_effect` to the original `__init__` method didn't work - the `foo()` mock still registered no calls.) Thanks this nearly defeated me!

Comment: In your first solution instead of the line `mock_parent_init.return_value = None` you could specify this thing right in the patch definition, ie. `@patch("Derived.Parent.__init__", return_value=None)`.