# Mocking initialization step and adding method calls to mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, constructor, mocking, patch

I have a class method where I instantiate a configuration class and then call a method on that class:

```
from config.ConfigB import ConfigB

class FileRunner(object):
  def runProcess(self, cfgA)
    cfgB = ConfigB(cfgA)
    print(cfgB.createvalue())
```

I have the following test class set up to try and test the method, but it isn't working:

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock imort MagicMock
import mock
from FileRunner import FileRunner

class TestFileRunner(unittest.TestCase):
  @mock.patch('ConfigB.ConfigB.__init__')
  def test_methodscalled(self, cfgB):

    cfgA = MagicMock()

    fileRunner = FileRunner()

    cfgB.return_value = None
    cfgB.return_value.createValue.return_value = 17

    fileRunner.runProcess(cfgA)
```

But when I test the class I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'createValue'
```

I also tried writing the test class like this:

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock imort MagicMock
import mock
from FileRunner import FileRunner

class TestFileRunner(unittest.TestCase):
  @mock.patch('ConfigB.ConfigB.__init__')
  def test_methodscalled(self, cfgB):

    cfgA = MagicMock()

    fileRunner = FileRunner()

    cfgBMock = mock.Mock()
    cfgBMock.createValue.return_value = 17

    cfgB.return_value = cfgBMock

    fileRunner.runProcess(cfgA)
```

But when I try this I get the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'Mock'
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to test my class?

*Edit: Here is the solution based on comments below:

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock imort MagicMock
import mock
from FileRunner import FileRunner

class TestFileRunner(unittest.TestCase):
  @mock.patch('ConfigB.ConfigB.__init__')
  @mock.patch('ConfigB.ConfigB.createValue')
  def test_methodscalled(self, createValue, cfgB):

    cfgA = MagicMock()

    fileRunner = FileRunner()


    createValue.return_value = 17

    cfgB.return_value = None

    fileRunner.runProcess(cfgA)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock parent class \_\_init\_\_ method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349855/mock-parent-class-init-method)

Comment: Init [may not return non-None value](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__), or a TypeError is raised – as you've observed. If you want to mock `ConfigB.createvalue`, should you not `@mock.patch('ConfigB.ConfigB.createvalue')`?

Comment: @IljaEverilä that worked. I have added in my updated test method. Thanks.

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer instead of part of the question. That way, the question won't look like it needs answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Don Kirby, I have put my solution as an answer to the question:

```
import unittest.mock import MagicMock

from FileRunner import FileRunner

class TestFileRunner(unittest.TestCase):
  @mock.patch('ConfigB.ConfigB.__init__')
  @mock.patch('ConfigB.ConfigB.createValue')
  def test_methodscalled(self, createValue, cfgB):
    cfgA = MagicMock()
    fileRunner = FileRunner()
    createValue.return_value = 17
    cfgB.return_value = None
    fileRunner.runProcess(cfgA)
```