# How to patch class constructor with pytest?

Tags: mocking, pytest, patch

I have a class `SiteManger` that I would like to patch in a unit test of my `main` function (pytest==6.2.5, python 3.10.1):

```py
from src.data_interface import DataInterface

class SiteManager:

    def __init__(self, time_span, process_id):
        self._time_span = time_span
        self._data_interface = DataInterface(self._time_span, process_id)
        self._sites = self._data_interface.create_sites()
 ...
```

The class `SiteManager` uses another class `DataInterface`.

If I patch `SiteManager`, I would expect that the original constructor of `SiteManager` **is not called** in the test. However, my test of `main` returns an error that occurs while running the original constructor of `SiteManager` shown above (because the code of `DataInterface` contains an error).

=> How can I correctly patch the `SiteManager` class, **so that my unit test for `main` does not depend on patched classes and their sub dependencies**?

If `DataInterface` contains an error, only the unit test for `DataInterface` should fail, not the unit tests for `main` or `SiteManager`.

My test of main:

```py
from src.main import main
from mock import patch


class TestMain:

    @patch('src.site.site_manager.SiteManager')
    @patch('src.simulation.simulation.Simulation')
    @patch('src.time_utils.create_time_span', return_value=['Y2015'])
    @patch('builtins.print')
    def test_main(self, mocked_print, mocked_create_time_span, mocked_simulation, mocked_site_manager):

        main()

        #mocked_site_manager.__init__.assert_called_once()
        #mocked_get_message.__init__.assert_called_once()
```

main.py:

```py
from src.site.site_manager import SiteManager
from src.simulation.simulation_mode import SimulationMode
from src.simulation.simulation import Simulation
from src.time_utils import create_time_span


def main():
    simulation_mode = SimulationMode.DETERMINISTIC  # SimulationMode.select()
    time_span = create_time_span(2015, 2017, 5)  # for example ['Y2015']
    process_id = 39
    co2_cost = 0  # input('CO2 cost: ')

    site_manager = SiteManager(time_span, process_id)
    simulation = Simulation(simulation_mode, time_span, co2_cost, site_manager)
    simulation.run()
    # simulation.show_evaluation()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```py
self = <src.data_interface.DataInterface object at 0x0000023603665C60>, time_span = ['Y2015'], process_id = 39

    def __init__(self, time_span, process_id):
        years = ', '.join(time_span)
        self._scenario_id = '40100'
        self._country_id = '9'

>       connection = sqlite3.connect('../input/industrial_database.sqlite')
E       sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Comment: you need to patch where it is imported which in this case is in `src.main`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using @patch.object instead of @patch did the trick:

```py
from src.main import main
from src.site.site_manager import SiteManager
from src.simulation.simulation import Simulation
import src.time_utils as time_utils
from mock import patch, MagicMock


class MockedSiteManager:
    pass


class TestMain:

    def site_manager_init_mock(self, time_span, process_id):
        pass

    def simulation_init_mock(self, simulation_mode, time_span, co2_cost, site_manager):
        self.run = MagicMock()

    @patch.object(SiteManager, '__init__', site_manager_init_mock)
    @patch.object(Simulation, '__init__', simulation_init_mock)
    @patch.object(time_utils, 'create_time_span', return_value=['Y2015'])
    def test_main(self, foo):
        try:
            main()
        except Exception as exc:
            assert False, f"main raised an exception {exc}"
        main()
```

Comment: With this solution I get TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'MagicMock'

Comment: found solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349855/mock-parent-class-init-method